# How to calculate the magnetic and electric fields in an electrical system with arbitrary geometry?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

What physics and mathematics are involved in calculating the fields around an electrical system of arbitrary geometry? Is it possible to describe a system in 3D, assign physical properties to the matter (e.g. resistivity and permittivity), specify a source of electrical energy, and calculate the electric and magnetic fields that will be generated?

Perhaps my question is better stated in the form of a concrete example. Supposed I create a model of an LC circuit consisting of a capacitor, an inductor, the wires that connect the two, and the wires that will be plugged into an outlet to provide a source of AC electrical energy. What are the underlying physics and mathematics that would allow me to calculate the electric and magnetic fields that will be produced in space? Wikipedia has a nice [artist’s rendition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit#mediaviewer/File:Tuned_circuit_animation_3.gif) of energy oscillating between the electric field of the capacitor and the magnetic field of the inductor, but the fields in any real LC circuit will be vastly more complex.

I understand the full answer to this question may be far too broad to post here, so any references you can recommend would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for software and not physics. Perhaps [Software Recommendations (beta)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be better suited for this question?

Comment: "What mathematical and computational tools exist to calculate the fields around an electrical system of arbitrary geometry?" Seems like a computational physics question, so he should be allowed to post it here or in scicomp. Also see the last bullet of the first paragraph [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). He is not specifically asking for software to solve a concrete problem. He's interested in the general techniques.

Comment: I realized from the previous comments that my question was too broad and edited it to focus on the physics. Apologies for not clarify the edit with a comment, but I didn't realize new users could comment on their own questions.

Comment: The question (v4) seems _too broad._